# Converting PDF to Markdown in Python with structure preservation

Tags: python, pdf, markdown, document-conversion, pdfminersix

I need to convert a PDF text document to Markdown and maintaining its structure (ie. indexed numbered headers and subheaders should have their correspective number of hashtags # in markdown to keep the same structure tree).
I have explored alone `PDFMinersix` but I am basically extracting text and I don't see a functionality capable of mapping the structure tree to markdown format, or am I wrong?

For me it's important to convert the document to text and being able to retain structure tree hierarchy. Either in 1 or 2 steps is the same for me.

Any recommendations for Python libraries or best practices that have proven effective in similar scenarios? I am looking for a solution that could scale hundreds of documents and so possibly nothing hardcoded, even though the documents will actually share most of the structure and indexing.

Comment: Checkout https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html library, I stumbed upon it via googlesearching your problem I saw someone doing what you wanted with that but I accidently closed it before I could help you.

Comment: some PDFs have a plain-text version and a table of contents embedded in the metadata (you can see that in some PDF viewers and I think also [pdfinfo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfinfo))... so if all your PDFs have that, I'd go for that...

Comment: Am I wrong or `PyMuPDF` is able to extract text like `PDFminer.six` but does not convert to markdown format the structure of the document. I still need to manually write when it needs to create markdown headers and subheaders in the same way I am doing currently with `PDFminer.six`

Comment: The most powerful pdf parser I know of is https://unstructured-io.github.io/unstructured/core/partition.html and it seems like a small step to take their list of "elements" to markdown; however, I have only seen basic joins of all the text in various examples.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Try llama_parse with result_type="markdown" - this worked for me

code:

```
from llama_parse import LlamaParse  # pip install llama-parse

parser = LlamaParse(
    api_key="...",  # you will need an API key, get it from https://cloud.llamaindex.ai/
    result_type="markdown"  # "markdown" and "text" are available
)

documents = parser.load_data("./my_file.pdf")
```

Comment: LlamaParse looks interesting, but not usable to anyone working on enterprise documents unless they have clearance for that API.

Comment: I'm also curious to know what might be happening behind the scenes? I'm also trying to parse digital pdfs, but layout is a big pain (scanned pdfs is a different ballgame altogether). Shed some insights if possible.